# What is the mainstream Islamic view of Tasis (incorporation)?

Tags: practical-islam, hadith-interpretation, books

Major Islamic scholar, [Ibn Taymiyyah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Taymiyyah), [wrote the book](http://self.gutenberg.org/articles/eng/Ibn_Taymiyah)

"Naqd at-Ta'sis  (Criticism of incorporation)"

I have searched for this work but have found nothing freely available on the Internet.  I am trying to understand the framework for a practical Islamic economic system.  I am debating the pros and cons of corporate entities in this framework.  Without Islamic references, I am just speculating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are referring to [*Naqd Assāss at-Taqdīs*](https://www.kutub-pdf.com/book/%D9%86%D9%82%D8%B6-%D8%A3%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%B3-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D9%82%D8%AF%D9%8A%D8%B3.html), rather than *Naqd at-Ta'sīs*. I do not have an account on this site, so I cannot vouch for the authenticity of the copy posted there.

Note that:

- This book was written in two large volumes, but only a small portion of the book is preserved in manuscripts, out of which only a smaller portion is in print.
- There are versions out there that are not authenticated (you may find them under the presumed authentication of Ibn Qāssim, as an example).
- There are books citing a version printed in Mecca by Maktabat al-Hukūma in 1391 A.H. but it is not clear by whom or when that old copy was authenticated (if at all).
- This book will neither help you with Islamic economic system nor corporate entities. It is a book about the names and attributes of Allah that refutes some of the misconceptions in another book called *Assāss at-Taqdīs* that presumably denied some of Allah's names and attributes.

Answer (score 2):

In fact the book title as presented creates some confusion ibn Qayyim al-Jawziya listed about 350 works of his teacher ibn Taymiyyah many of them -as usual in the Arabic literature- are known by parts of a title or what we can call a name they are known by. For example the book commonly reffered to by [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sahih_al-Bukhari) in fact is entitled: *al-Jami' ul-musnadu as-sahihu al-mukhtassar min omori rassuli Allahi salla Allahu 'alayhi wa salam wa sunatihi wa ayyamih* الجامع المسند الصحيح المختصر من أُمور رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلّم وسننه وأيامه so many books have a title they are known or usually referred to with while the correct title is somewhat different.

To be honest all sites I've consulted so far (English/German) that quote a list of books of ibn Taymiyyah present in this list a book entitled "Naqd at-Ta'sis" (in Latin letters) which can't be found in Arabic sources -at least I couldn't find it-. So it seems that somebody posted a book title and others followed him blindly. Note that if such a book exists the title may mean Discussion/Criticism (or the Annulment/Refutation) of Foundation/Incorporation.
In Arabic language you may find usually find in such a list, book titles containing "Naqd" (I could make out 7, note that in Arabic there's a clear difference between نقض and نقد which both maybe transliterated "Naqd") or "Ta'sis" (without a preposition).

So among the books ibn Taymiyyah wrote there's a book which has "two known 
titles":

> بيان تلبيس الجهمية في تأسيس بدعهم الكلامية *أو* نقض تأسيس الجهمية (See for example [here](http://waqfeya.com/book.php?bid=3893))
>   <sub>Transliteration</sub>
>   Bayan talbees al-Jahmiyyah fi ta'sis bida'ihim al-Kalamiyah *aw* Naqd Ta'sis al-Jahmiyyah
>   <sub>Translation of my own</sub>
>   Demonstration of the donning of the Jahimi (sect) in the foundation of their Kalami innovation *or* Annulment of the foundation of the [Jahmi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jahmi) (sect)

Again this book as the one @III-AK-III is referring to is far away of being related to economy matters. In fact it is rather a refutation of the theological fundamentals of a sect or the followers of [Jahm ibn Safwan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jahm_bin_Safwan). It also seems to be a response of [ar-Razi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fakhr_al-Din_al-Razi)'s Ta'sis at-Taqdis تأسيس التقديس or Asas at-Taqdis [أساس التقديس](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj9gbrHqPPbAhUS2KQKHU-dCUYQFgg0MAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Farchive.org%2Fdetails%2FAssau_Taghdis&usg=AOvVaw1NFZwrysrshjiPBomiG6Cm).

I found some articles instead claiming that ibn Taymiyyah's economical views and opinions can be found scattered in his books and fatwas.